# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-12

Need help. I am getting crash described in title from users on Samsung phones.
I have added `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` as `myFlags or FLAG_IMMUTABLE` to all my PendingIntents. App is not crashing on my Pixel 3.
I've tried to add `workmanager` version 2.7.0 which was recommended in other answers for similar questions but it is still crashing.

Does someone have any hints about it?

Comment: Found this issue when I tried Firebase Auth UI. NO answers in other posts are working.

Comment: I'm getting this error from my `paho.client.mqttv3` dependency.

Comment: @JacobFerrero Thanks, but I don't have this one in my project

Comment: The `paho.client.mqttv3` is not updated from July 2020. Maybe is that?

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same error and I just find a solution.

Adding `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'` in my  dependencies solve the error for me.

In fact, I have added every dependency specified here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies, and it works, so I delete one by one, and I found that the one that correct the error is play-services-auth.

Comment: It may help because I had older version of this dependency.
Thx, I'll try it later. At this time I have just downgraded the version.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked and solved the problem with Firebase Auth UI.